# How to use gutentags for ctags updates and vim-easytags for c++ syntax highlighting?

Tags: vim, ctags

Gutentags seems to be faster at tags management, however vim-easytags has some extra syntax highlighting depending on tag kind, mainly for c++.

Is there anyway I can use them together?

Comment: In case you don't get any answer with these plugins, [lh-tags](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-tags) has both features integrated into one plugin. However, by default highlighting based on tags is inhibited as there is no way to update the highlighting in background, at best we may be able to update dictionaries (for spelling), but I haven't took time to implement a convoluted workaround.

Comment: @LucHermitte Hey, it looks like you have a great plugin there, I'll check it out! Thanks.